# Codeigniter 2.2.6 find min value from sql column

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have an error:

```
Array to string conversion
```

In my model I have this:

```
public function get_min(){      
    $this->db->select_min('sq_place');
    $query = $this->db->get('places');
    return $query->result();    
}
```

In my dump data I got this:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[32]
      public 'sq_place' => string '110' (length=3)
```

I use CodeIgniter v 2.2.6. How to convert this to string like 110 without errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$result = $query->result_array() ; // to get response as array.
```

Then. Access your string value as

```
$val = $result[0]['sq_place'];
echo $val; //This should print your string val and wont give mentioned error
```

Comment: In my controller I have: $this->data['sqv'] = $this->place_m->get_min(); and In my view <?php echo $sqv; ?> same result.

Comment: In your view it should be like,  $sqv1 = $sqv[0]; echo $sqv1->sq_place;

Comment: Nothing the same result. I know I am close but something is wrong.

Comment: can you please share the var_dump($sqv) in your view?

Comment: I find the solution $sqv[0]['sq_place'] in my view

Comment: @VasilisGreece this is the correct answer. You should accept this if solved.

Answer (score 0):

Okay as I understood you need to return min value as a string (return params). So here is the best way:

```
public function get_min(){      
   $this->db->select_min('sq_place');
   $query = $this->db->get('places');
   $min = 0;
   if($query->num_rows > 0){
      // It returns single row as an object from database
      $min = $query->row()->sq_place;
   }
   return $min ;    
}
```

When you will print **$min** value then you will get single value itself. Let me know if you need result in a different manner.